# Can MatPlotlib make charts with a deviation from zero?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I'm trying to make a chart like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

My original thoughts were to do it with MatPlotLib. I haven't found any examples of doing it with that library, is it possible or should I look to a different Python library?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14958707?

Comment: Yes, Matplotlib can make both those plots. The first is a stem plot.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stem_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-stem-plot-py. The second is just plotting different width lines centred on the data value, which will require a bit of work, but is not that hard

Comment: For the second plot you could try [`ax.errorbar(...., xerr=...)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/errorbar_limits.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-errorbar-limits-py).  Similar to [scatterplot with xerr and yerr with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707147/scatterplot-with-xerr-and-yerr-with-matplotlib).